# bitcoin compile (.undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)')

Tags: c++, makefile, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm getting error after make command like,

**undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)'**

and in last

**Makefile:774: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed**

**make: **[all-recursive] Error 1**

I have followed all steps given here:-

https://www.toshblocks.com/bitcoin/compile-bitcoin-source-code-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Output :-

```
 Making all in src
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    make[3]: Entering directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin'
    make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin'
      CXXLD    bitcoind
    libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o): In function `generateBlocks(std::shared_ptr<CReserveScript>, int, unsigned long, bool)':
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:122: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:122: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::CreateNewBlock(CScript const&, bool)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:128: undefined reference to `IncrementExtraNonce(CBlock*, CBlockIndex const*, unsigned int&)'
    libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o): In function `getmininginfo(JSONRPCRequest const&)':
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:216: undefined reference to `nLastBlockWeight'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:217: undefined reference to `nLastBlockTx'
    libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o): In function `getblocktemplate(JSONRPCRequest const&)':
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:521: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:521: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::CreateNewBlock(CScript const&, bool)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:533: undefined reference to `UpdateTime(CBlockHeader*, Consensus::Params const&, CBlockIndex const*)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:3888: recipe for target 'bitcoind' failed
    make[2]: *** [bitcoind] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    Makefile:10190: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    Makefile:774: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How to solve this error and compile bitcoin source code successfully?

Comment: Most likely a missing library. The steps you are referring to say something like  LDFLAGS="-L/home/theusername/bitcoin/db4/lib/" but they don't have something like -l<library> (e.g. -lbitcoin ?)

Comment: I bet that the autogen or configure didn't finish. Make sure that configure doesn't stop with an error.

Comment: both ./autogen.sh and ./configure finished with no errors. @TheQuantumPhysicist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial helped me to solve the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0A91Yx9juQ

By, Following Unix build notes,

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-UNIX.md

and downloading needed dependencies can solve the problem. 
I think problem occurred due to bad installation of Berkeley DB,
and so i have remove all old files and then again followed steps from build-UNIX.md.

and download dependencies which are,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config bsdmainutils python3  

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libevent-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

This worked for me. Thank you!